# Connection on MySQL very slow between to OpenVZ CT

Tags: mysql, openvz

I created a private cloud with OpenVZ, with some CT linked by Venet.
One CT hosts a MySQL server, configured to listen on 192.168.1.21

When, from an other CT, I ping 192.168.1.21, I have a ping of 0.020ms, so very fast (Thanks Venet) :)

But, when I connect to MySQL (from CLI or PDO), it takes about 20 seconds to authenticate. The request after that step are very fast.

There is an URL to test, with a timer just for the MySQL connection: http://api.urdoor.com

My CT are TurnKey MySQL template and TurnKey Nginx templates, all for amd64.

How can I speed up that connection ?

I supposed that could be DNS checks, or something like that, but I already disabled DNS checks with `skip-name-resolve`.

Comment: Really needed that F bomb in there, huh.

Comment: Huh sorry, in France, we say that every time :/

Answer (score 0):

It was because the Nginx+PHP amd64 Turnkey package is wrong built. From a clean debian 7.0 install, it's working like a charm !